# Divides in function, but doesn't outside. Python 3.4

Tags: python-3.4

I have a somewhat weird issue. I'm supposed to take an inputted number, and if it's even divide it until it's odd. But. The code works inside the function, and the while loop, but it doesn't work when I try to return that value. It literally just returns the inputted value.

Code for reference:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number."))

def makeodd(num):
    while num % 2 == 0:
        num = num / 2
        print(num)
        return num

makeodd(num)

print(num)
```

I apologize that this is a bit basic. I'm looking for more of an explanation then a real solution. Although a solution would be nice. This is python 3.4 for reference. I looked around but couldn't actually find anything that was like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `makeodd(num)` to:

```
num = makeodd(num)
```

That puts the return value into `num`.

You could also use the return value directly in the print statement:

```
print(makeodd(num))
```

Comment: Thank you. feel kinda stupid for not figuring that out.